# I want to switch one tab to another tab on last element of current tab in javascript

Tags: javascript

i Write This code for that

```
$(document).on('keydown','form input :nth-last-child(3)',function(e){
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (keyCode == 9) {
      var $parent=$('form').parents('.ui-tabs');
      if($parent.length>0) {
         var tabid=$parent.attr("id");
         var current= $( "#"+tabid ).tabs( "option", "active" );
         $( "#"+tabid ).tabs({ active: current +1 });
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: If its javascript, tag it javascript. Not java!

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as car is to cardboard

Comment: This is not java related! Ask your question in javascript tag.

Comment: Can you post a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Along with a more complete description of the problem. What are you seeing? What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo with want you want to achieve if i understood it correctly:
[JS Bin](http://output.jsbin.com/xiyibi/)

You should set the active tab options on the parent element on which you initialised jquery-ui `tabs()`, not on any particular `#tab-{$id}`.

Below i also added the js code for it:

```
$(document).on('keydown','input',function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

  if (keyCode == 9) {

    if($(this).is(':last-child')) {
      var current= $( '#tabs' ).tabs( "option", "active" );

      $('#tabs').tabs({ active: current +1 });
    }
  }
});
```

Let me know if you have trouble making it work.